# How to get timestamp in kwargs like run_id in Airflow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow

As we get `run_id` in Airflow, how to get timestamp(ts)?

Comment: How do you get `run_id`? If you are fetching it from db then from the same table `dag_run` you can fetch `execution_date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:
In your task set **provide_context=True**

```
bye_operator = PythonOperator(
  task_id='bye_task',
  python_callable=print_goodbye,
  provide_context=True,
  dag=dag
)
```

Second:
Ensure you are passing the known arguments into your callback function:

```
def print_goodbye(**kwargs):
    ts = kwargs.get('ts', None)
    print(ts)
    return 'Good bye world!'
```